# How to seed AspNetUserRoles in ASP.NET Core 6 and EF Core 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core

My sample project is [here](https://github.com/phasetr/ASP.NET-Core/tree/main/EFCoreQuestionSO20230315).

I have several related problems, but the main problem is seeding to `AspNetUserRoles`. I would like to add fundamental data, and I can seed data to `AspNetUsers` and `AspNetRoles`. However the same approach seems inappropriate to `AspNetUserRoles`.

`ApplicationUserRole` class creates the table `ApplicationUserRole`, and is not assigned to `AspNetUserRoles`. This is the 1st problem.

The second problem is configuration to `ApplicationUserRole`. I do not give the same properties as `AspNetUserRoles`, for example, `ApplicationUserRole` does not have foreign keys. I looked up some official pages, e.g. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/ef/core/change-tracking/relationship-changes) or [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key), and wrote some more codes. However I do not have proper codes. Of course, my final goal is proper seeding to `AspNetRoles`, but the code for `ApplicationUserRole` has something wrong, I think.

Thanks in advance.

I followed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-7.0), and created `ApplicationUser` and `ApplicationRole` class. This seems to be proper. But `ApplicationUserRole` class seems to be improper. I checked the [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62152190/seed-database-aspnetuserroles-table-in-asp-net-core-3-1-mvc), but I have the error,

> The entity type 'IdentityUserRole' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'. For more information on keyless entity types, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2141943.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure use the same Key type for Identity related entities

Assume you are using `Guid` as Identity primary key

- ApplicationUserRole.cs

```cs
public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<Guid>
```

- ApplicationRole.cs

```cs
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<Guid>
```

- Program.cs

```cs
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
```

And you don't need to set key for IdentityUserRole in Configuration

- ApplicationUserRoleConfiguration.cs

delete this row

```cs
builder.HasKey(m => new {m.UserId, m.RoleId});
```

---

In addition, you could use `ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly()` for `IEntityTypeConfiguration`

```cs
builder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, and I can solve my problem! I changed `ApplicationUserRole` type to `public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<string>`, then I can delete `builder.HasKey(m => new {m.UserId, m.RoleId}); ` and EF Core does not create a new `ApplicationUserRole`! Thank you again for your time.

Comment: Great ! If your want use `string` for you key type, you could just use `: IdentityUserRole` (withou the <string>) @phasetr